# Flex easy set buttonmode to all buttons

Tags: apache-flex, button

is there an easy way to set the buttonMode to true to all my buttons in my application?
I thought to create a custom component which extends the s:Button and set there buttonMode to true but I wonder if there is an easier way like with CSS.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What behavior are you trying to achieve by setting buttonMode = true?  Maybe there is a way to get that behavior in another way.

Comment: I want to display the hand cursor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either try writing a crawler which would walk through all your object at runtime, or something like this:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, parseItem, true);
```

and then:

```
function parseItem(e:Event):void{
  if (e.target is Button)
      e.target.buttonMode = true;
}
```

Each item which is added to the stage should go through this event (even if only its parent is added to the display list).

Of course you'll have to add this event listener before anything is added to the stage actually!

Comment: Obviously it will have some impact on the performance, every DisplayObject added to the stage will dispatch this event, but it is only a problem if you are continuously adding and removing stuff from stage. If you do this less often than once per step the difference should not be noticeable. If you are working with Flex Framework it can be a bit worse, but if your app is well written it also should go unnoticed. Besides you can remove the listener once you don't need it anymore.

Answer (score 4):

As Wade said, the skin is a good way to go.  While setting buttomMode="true" on the skin won't work the way you want, you can set the host button's buttonMode from the skin like so:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import spark.components.Button;

        override protected function commitProperties():void
        {
            super.commitProperties();
            hostComponent.buttonMode = true;
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do this with a skin and css.  Copy the default ButtonSkin to a custom skin class and set buttonMode="true" on the skin.  (If that doesn't work you can try to set  hostComponent.buttonMode = true on creation complete.)  Then set the skin for s:Button to your custom skin in your css.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think you have any other option that creating a custom Button.

You could monkey patch the original Button component but I wouldn't recommand this pratice.

Comment: Damn.. I think I'll file a JIRA issue on adobe's jira

Comment: In that case, either create a shell script that replace all your buttons or just monkey patch the Button component

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest Maurycy's approach or you could just monkey patch the Button class in your project. That might even be easier and it would not cause a performance hit.